# asp.net Validations Not working with confirmation box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a confirmation box.
The following code shows the yes / no confirm box, but this does not take care of validation.
If I have made the company name field compulsory, it enters a record, even when I have not entered the company name.

I have called this method in pageload event:

```
CreateConfirmBox(btnAddEnquiry, "Do You Really Want to Add ?");
```

Method definitions:

```
public void CreateConfirmBox(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn, string strMessage)
{
    btn.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return confirm('" + strMessage + "');");
}
```

aspx file

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddEnquiry" runat="server" 
     BackColor="#0000FF"
     ForeColor="LightSlateGray"
     OnClick="btnAddEnquiry_Click" 
     Text="Add Enquiry" Width="154px" />
```

Comment: aspx file...........<asp:Button ID="btnAddEnquiry" runat="server" BackColor="#0000FF" ForeColor="LightSlateGray"
                 OnClick="btnAddEnquiry_Click" Text="Add Enquiry" Width="154px" />

Comment: You can delete your comment. Use the code button next time :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Where's your RequiredFieldValidator?

Answer (score 2):

You are not handling any validations in your code.

I strongly suggest you to use the .NET Validation controls. They are good and barely have to write any code.

More info here;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Code Example;

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator IdD="RequiredFieldValidator2"
             ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
             Display="Static"
             Width="100%" runat="server">
             *
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

  <asp:Button ID="btn_Save"
             Text="Validate" 
             OnClick="btnSave_Click" 
             runat="server" />
```

If you don't want to implement validators and use only a confirm box and thus keeping the same functionality that you currently have, you can do so by using the OnCientClick of the button which will stop the PostBack if the user clicks No.

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnAddEnquiry" runat="server" 
              BackColor="#0000FF"
              ForeColor="LightSlateGray"
              OnClick="btnAddEnquiry_Click" 
              OnClientClient="javascript: return confirm('Do You Really Want to Add ?');"
              Text="Add Enquiry" Width="154px" />
```

Comment: Nice explaination... Btw, how do we use a confirm box along with .NET Validation controls? When I tried, the validation controls were overridden.

Comment: I don't think you can. Since .NET validations are meant to be meet at all times.

Comment: @Agius: Ok... lemme modify my question. How to use validation(.net control or otherwise but client-side) along with confirm box?

Comment: Can I ask you why not use required field validations / regular expression validators or other validation? To be honest I don't see why someone would want to use a confirmation box. Maybe if you highlight what you want to achieve I can help you better.

Comment: @agius: I am absolutely OK with using required field validations / regular expression validators or other validation. But along with that I want to use javascript confirm() on submit button click. I realize there're alternative ways to do so but am curious to know how can I achieve the specified functionality?

Comment: If clicking no, you want that the validation are ignored right?

Comment: http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-control-ASP-NET-Validator-Controls-Client-Side-validation-from-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: See, in my case, I had applied 'validation controls' & they worked fine. Then later on, I added the 'confirm box' on `OnClientClick`. Now, when I clicked on `Submit` without entering anything to test for validation & then clicked `Yes` on confirm box, the validations didn't work & as a result exception occurred. And I was shocked... Now what I wanted was that naturally, validations work in the above mentioned case. And thanks for your cooperation for this petty question.

Comment: You should check if the Page.IsValid in is true.